# Does all oozie action run in DataNode?

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

I am just getting started in oozie,I understand the architecture (oozie client,server and oozie server submit job to Yarn.) I see we have different oozie actions - java action,ssh, discp,shell etc does all these action that does not involve mapreduce or bigdata processing run inside hadoop cluster (i.e) in data nodes ?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34481536/2254048